# Failure on distributing go binary

Tags: go

I'm trying to make available a cli tool written in Go but I'm getting the following error when trying to install it using:

> go install github.com/myuser/mytool@latest

**The error:**

> go install: github.com/myuser/mytool@latest: module github.com/myuser/mytool@latest found (v0.0.1), but does not contain package github.com/myuser/mytool

I have created a v0.0.1 tag and added the binaries for release.

**Also tried**:

> go get -u github.com/myuser/mytool

Then I get no output and the binary is not installed.

**More Info**:

go.mod:

```
module github.com/myuser/mytool

go 1.17

require github.com/fatih/color v1.13.0

require (
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.11 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.14 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20211117180635-dee7805ff2e1 // indirect
)
```

Go version:

> go version go1.17.2 darwin/arm64

**Obs:** I can install any other tool on github in the same way as the above.

**EDIT**

Someone has voted to close the issue for lack of clarity. Would help if you could also be more clear and say what do you think I'm missing here.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. What is the import path of your `main` package?

Comment: Thanks @JimB. All go files sit in the root level of the repository and all of them live in the `main` package. I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: Go is reporting there is no package at `github.com/myuser/mytool`, so either the code is not there, or it is called something else.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on creating a cli tool starting with the prefix `go`?

Comment: There are lots of binaries with a go prefix, like `gopls`, `goimports`, `golist`, etc, all installable via `go install` (and note that `go get` is deprecated as a method for installation, use `go install`)

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be that you didn't publish this as a package. check out [this](https://golang.org/doc/modules/developing) link for information on modules and publishing.

I have a shell script setup for one of my projects to upload it as a package, shown below:

```sh
!/bin/bash
git tag $1
git push origin $1
GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org go list -m github.com/myuser/mytool@$1
```

> `$1` refers to the first parameter of the script, which is the version number.